# Send message via telegram bot using Firebase onCreate();

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send message to an user when a node is created in firebase realtime database. For now talking of telegram bot this is how it is triggered.

```
const bot = express()

bot.use(cors({ origin: true }))

bot.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    //bot functioning here
    return res.status(200).send({
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id,
        reply_to_message_id: messageIdtoReply,
        text: `Some Text`,
        parse_mode: 'HTML'
    })
})

export const router = functions.https.onRequest(bot)
```

This was general code how I send a telegram message via bot. This gets triggered when a user sends message to the bot and then bot replies.

But I want the bot to send a message to use when there is a new node created in Firebase Realtime Database.

```
export const sendTelegramMsg = functions.database
    .ref('/path/')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const msgText = snapshot.val() 

        return . . .
    })
```

The actual question that arises is how do I trigger bot message send using on create. Even if I hard-code the Telegram UIDs to whom I want to send the message and use the same code above `res.send...` inside the `onCreate()` then it will say something like res not recognized. I also cannot trigger the bot code as I won't have the required JSON.

Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Clarification: Send a message using telegram bot when a new node value is create in firebase realtime database.

Comment: so if a new node is created you want to send that information to the user on the webpage, did i understand you?

Comment: @Ifaruki Yes you can say. For test purpose let's just send a message `Node created` when the node is created. You got it.